# How can I add a string to the start of the array on matlab?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, append

I'm trying to add a string to a "cell" type value of matlab. I want to add it as the first value of the "array" variable, without deleting the actual first value.

What I have:

```matlab
array = {'A001','A002','B001','B002','B003','B004','C001','C004'}

add_to_start = 'Time'
```

What I want:

```matlab
array = {'Time','A001','A002','B001','B002','B003','B004','C001','C004'}
```

**EDIT**

Actually my input array is:

```matlab
array = {'A001','A002','B001','B002','B003','B004','C001';'','','','','','',''}
```

How can I delete the empty row?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array to add an element to your cell:

```
mycell = ['time',mycell];
```

Or using the colon operator:

```
mycell = {'time',mycell{:}};
```

Comment: I obtain this error:

Error using horzcat
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent. Consider converting input arrays to the same type before
concatenating.

Comment: my array is 2x6, but when I open it is 1x6

Comment: I'm only considering your example. Both solution will work with your example. I guess that your cell is of dimension `n x 1` and not `1 x n` which is not the same since a cell or an array have at least two dimensions in matlab.